# Translation with Thymeleaf in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf, translation

In my HTML page I'm loading my translation with Thymeleaf like that:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.resetData()" th:text="#{general.reset}">Reset</button>
```

Is it possible to translate text which is hard coded in my JavaScript code?
'Loading Data...' should be translated with th:text="#{general.loadingData}" <- but this is the way I would translate it in my HTML page, this doesn't work for JavaScript Code. All the translations are in a messeges_en.properties file.

How can I translate the text in JavaScript?

```
function(request: any) {
    asLoading.show('Loading Data...');
    return request || $q.when(request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl).

[FormatJs](https://formatjs.io) is a modular collection of JavaScript libraries for internationalization that are focused on formatting numbers, dates, and strings for displaying to people.

It has [support](https://formatjs.io/guides/basic-i18n/) for [ICU message format](http://icu-project.org/icu4jdemos.html) (International Components for Unicode) which is also well supported in java as well.

So you can expose your translations in ICU message format and consume them from both java and javascript.

In general, it is better to treat javascript and java code as separate applications as opposed to treating javascript as something that is tacked on top of a java template language like thymeleaf.